# How to get data a ZMQ_PUB service?

Tags: zeromq, publish-subscribe

Can I publisher service receive data from an external source and send them to the subscribers?

In the `wuserver.cpp` example, the data are generated from the same script.

Can I write a `ZMQ_PUBLISHER` entity, which receives data from external data source / application ... ?

[image]

In this affirmation:

> There is one more important thing to know about `PUB-SUB` sockets: you do not know precisely when a subscriber starts to get messages. Even if you start a subscriber, wait a while, and then start the publisher, the subscriber will always miss the first messages that the publisher sends. This is because as the subscriber connects to the publisher (something that takes a small but non-zero time), the publisher may already be sending messages out.

Does this mean, that a **`PUB-SUB`** ZeroMQ pattern is performed to a best effort - UDP style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q1**:
>  Can I write a **`ZMQ_PUBLISHER`** entity, which receives data from external data source/application?

**A1**: Oh sure, this is why ZeroMQ is so helping us in designing smart  [distributed-systems](/questions/tagged/distributed-systems). Just imagine the **`PUB`**-side process to also have other { .bind() | .connect() }-calls, so as to establish such other links to data-feeder(s), and you are done to operate the wished to have scheme. In [distributed-systems](/questions/tagged/distributed-systems) this gives you a new freedom to smart integrate heterogeneous systems to talk to each other in a very efficient way.

---

> **Q2**:
> Does this mean, that a **`PUB-SUB`** ZeroMQ pattern is performed to a best effort - UDP style?

**A2**: No, it has another meaning. The newly declared subscriber entities at some uncertain moment start to negotiate their respective subscription-topic filtering and such a ( distributed ) process takes some a-priori unknown time. Unless until the new / changed topic-filter policy was established, there is nothing to go into the **`SUB`**-side exgress interface to meet a `.recv()`-call, so no one can indeed tell, when that will get happened, can he?

On a higher level, there is another well known dichotomy of ZeroMQ -- Zero-Warranty Principle -- expect to either get delivered a complete message or none at all, which prevents the framework users from a need to handle any kind of damaged / inconsistent message-payloads. Either OK, or `None`. That's a great warranty. The more for [distributed-systems](/questions/tagged/distributed-systems).